# django unique constraint failed user_id

Tags: python, django

django unique constraint failed salebook_saleman.user_id

model.py:

```
class Saleman(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Saleman)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_text = models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name
```

view.py:

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        email = request.POST['email']
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
        new_saleman = Saleman.objects.create(name=username,password=password)
        if newsaleman is not None:
            new_saleman.save()
        if new_user is not None:
            new_user.save()
            context = {'Username':username}
            return render(request,"salebook/index.html",context)
    else:
        context = {'error_message':'Register Fail'}
        return render(request,"salebook/register.html",context)


def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            context = {'Username':username}
            return render(request,"salebook/index.html",context)
        else:
            context = {'error_message':'User is locked'}
            return render(request,"salebook/login.html",context)
    else:
        context = {'error_message':'Null User or Wrong Password'}
        return render(request,"salebook/login.html",context)
else:
    return render_to_response('salebook/login.html')
```

Not really sure what it means or what's causing it.
Let me know if there's an easy fix. Thanks!
Update:
The error is:

```
 File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
field,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 231, in add_field
self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 199, in _remake_table
self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 112, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:salebook_saleman.user_id
```

At First I try to extend my model saleman by using abstractUser,and this error happen.When I redo my code,it still alive.Sorry,I don't know what happened to my code.

Comment: Please post the error you got and try to explain what you were trying to do when getting the error.

Comment: The easy fix is to sorround your `User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)` with try except , but believe me you don't want the easy fix here. You have a lot of other things to tackle.

Comment: Sorry,I update my error

Comment: It looks as if you are saving your passwords in plain text in the `Saleman` model. You should not be doing this. The Django User model takes care of hashing passwords for you.

Comment: I remove the code you tell about,the error is still alive

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you've lost a '_' here:

```
if newsaleman is not None:
        new_saleman.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your `Saleman` model used to have a foreign key or one-to-one field to the user model. You need to create a new migration and then run it to remove the field from the database.

```
./manage.py makemigrations salebook
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: When I run instruction migrate in cmd,this error happens.

Comment: Yes,I make my Saleman model have one-to-one field before I redo my code.

Comment: I can't debug that error because I do not have your models, migration files and database in front of me. You might find it easiest to drop the database, delete the migrations and start again.